# Detect a device from within a browser

Tags: security, browser, identification

Several platforms offer security mechanisms to identify if a user ever logged in from a certain device. If you login from a computer you never did they'll ask you special questions on login. How do they recognize a device? Is this only be geo localization (which would not cover multiple devices in the same region, would it?). Or only with cookies which would cause trouble on cookie cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, cookies is really the only way you can do this. The server stores whatever information it can about your device it can get from the browser in a cookie. By geo-location I assume you mean the location of the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The ones I've seen do this are all based on cookies and do cause trouble if users delete their cookies.

Doing this by IP address would cause headaches for anyone behind a web-proxy or shared connection. It would also be painful for mobile users in transit where the gateway is changing based on cell tower connections. Geolocation would also present problems for mobile users in transit.